# RequestMapping with login method returns 404 error

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have create simple registration/login methods with RequestMapping annotations. I need to return to the home page if the registration/login is succesful, otherwise go back to registerform.html/login.html.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/registeruser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String createUser(@RequestParam(value = "name") String firstName,
                         @RequestParam(value = "surname") String lastName,
                         @RequestParam(value = "username") String username,
                         @RequestParam(value = "email") String email,
                         @RequestParam(value = "password") String password
                         )
{
    User user = new User(password, username, firstName, lastName, email,null,null);
    new UserDAO().createUser(user);

    return "redirect:index";
}


@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String userLogin(@RequestParam(value = "username") String username,
                         @RequestParam(value = "password") String password)
{

    boolean login = new UserDAO().logIn(username, password);
    if(login){
        return "redirect:index";
    }
    else{
        return "login";
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

It's a simple login/registration app in SpringBoot. For the `createUser` method once the data are inserted in the database I would like to return to the homepage (/src/main/resoures/static/index.html). On the otherhand if `login`method returns `false` I would like the login.html to load again.

Comment: *I get an error 404 from the return statement.*: sorry, but that doesn't mean anything to me. What are you doing, what do you expect to happen, and what happens instead? Be extremely precise.

Comment: the problem is that it doesn't redirect the user to the desired html page